# fragment access widget from another fragment in the same activity

Tags: java, android

I want to change the text in text view in fragment1 by clicking a button in fragment2, i managed to do that by declaring the text view as `static` so i can change the text by  `Fragment1.textv.setText("hi");`  , is that ok and what is the best way to do this.

```
  static  textv ;
@Override
public View onCreateView(  LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   final   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_beam_rec, container, false);

    textv= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textview);

           return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Most common approach is using interfaces to 'speak' from fragment A to fragment B (you would need to communicate through the activity):

  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
- You can also use an Event-bus library like Otto, register the fragments that you want to update, and from the other fragment post an update:

  http://square.github.io/otto/

Answer (score 1):

as  user3806331 stated you need to use interfaces ,follow the link and you will find what you need.but be aware that having static reference to a widget is a bad practice ,because it may lead to memory leaks in some situations.